# Get a sticky random number in a often called function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, random

I am making a Guess number machine, supported by a book 'html5 game programming for dummies'. I got stuck at the function where the random number get called.

I tried to put it outside the function, but that doesn't work, because the number doesn't refresh then when there are no turns. I also tried to put it in my first if statement, so it will be called only the first time, but that gives an undefined error. Any1 who can help me?

code:

```
var turns = 3;

function Guess() {

    var randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100);

    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    if(turns == 3) {
        if(input == randNum) {
            output.innerHTML = 'Congratulations! Thats the right answer!';
            turns = 4;
        } else if(input > randNum) {
            output.innerHTML = 'The number is lower!';
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = 'The number is higher!';
        }
        turns--;
    } else if(turns == 2) {
        if(input == randNum) {
            output.innerHTML = 'Congratulations! Thats the right answer!';
            turns = 4;
        } else if(input > randNum) {
            output.innerHTML = 'The number is lower!';
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = 'The number is higher!';
        }
        turns--;
    } else if(turns == 1) {
        if(input == randNum) {
            output.innerHTML = 'Congratulations! Thats the right answer!';
            turns = 3;
        } else if(input > randNum) {
            output.innerHTML = 'The number is '+randNum+'. You lost!';
            turns = 3;
        } else {
            output.innerHTML = 'The number is '+randNum+'. You lost!';
            turns = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

PS. My code is also not really optimalized. Any1 have tips to optimalize my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to save the random number for when the function is ran again?

Comment: Yes exactly! I want to save the number, and refresh it when turns == 3

Answer (score 0):

It took me a little while to work out what you were asking here, but I think this is the answer you're looking for ...

Add this line outside the function

```
var turns = 3;
var randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100); // This one

function Guess() {
    // ...
```

And then this towards the end of the function:

```
    } else {
        output.innerHTML = 'The number is '+randNum+'. You lost!';
        turns = 3;
    }
    randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100); // This one
}
```

So now you're setting a random number when the document is loaded, and having it as a global variable that your function can access.  The user attempts 3 times to guess the number between 1 and 100 (pretty unreasonable challenge), and then when they run out of 'turns', the randNum gets reset to a new random number for the user to keep on guessing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The structure you gave me here helped my a lot. The code you gave me didn't work and turned undefined, but I customized it to the right way.

PS. Yes, it's not a nice challenge, but i'm just following the book excersises. By the way sorry for my bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed your function 'Guess()' to 'checkAnswer()', as that's more appropriate. Could shorten it down a lot as well.

```
var maxNum = 100;
var maxTurns = 3;
var turn = 1;
var ans;
var randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*maxNum);

var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function checkGuess(){
    if(input == randNum) {
        ans = 'Congratulations! Thats the right answer!';
        turn = 1;
        randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*maxNum);
    } else if (turn == maxTurns){
        ans = 'The number is ' + randNum + '. You lost!';
        turn = 1;
        randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*maxNum);
    } else if (input > randNum) {
        ans = 'The number is lower!';
        turn++;
    } else {
        ans = 'The number is higher!';
        turn++;
    }
    output.innerHTML = ans;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Nice how u shorten this code, but it tried it and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Let's see ... maybe it's something with the random() stuff, I once had problems with that as well. By the way: if you notice that things are quite repetitive in your code, try packing it into a function, maybe add parameters. Just like I did there. You'll end up with much more readable code. Another thing: you had to set 'turns' to 4 at the win and lost cases, because of the unneccessary 'turns--;'. Little copy&paste mistake there :D

Comment: Yeah, I am just still learning javascript and getting my code organised and readable is very important to me. Thanks for your help! I will mention your tips and use them.